# C++ Armadillo:- Equivalent to Matlab's bsxfun

Tags: c++, matlab, function, armadillo, bsxfun

Does Aramadillo have a general purpose equivalent to matlab's bsxfun, which performs element wise operations e.g bsxfun(@minus,A,B)? I have seen that Armadillo does have element wise multiplication and division, but no indication that a generalized function is available.

Comment: Um, the purpose of bsxfun is NOT to perform an operation on every element of a matrix. That is not what it does. You MAY be thinking of arrayfun, or cellfun.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe I my definition wasn't quite right. My understanding is the bsxfun(@minus,A,B) will perform an element wise subtraction of each corresponding element in A and B. Obviously I could just for a double for loop, and I notice Armadillo has element wise multiplication and division, but I can't see a more general bsxfun type operator.

Comment: Sigh. But that was NOT what you asked for! You asked for a function that will operate on every element of an array. Read your own question. BSXFUN performs a dyadic operation between specific pairs of array elements in TWO distinct arrays. So what is it that you really want?

Comment: OP has now been corrected with what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

While not exactly bsxfun(), there are two new functions added to [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) 3.4+ which are related to your question: [.each_col()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#each_colrow) and .each_row(). They allow a given vector operation to be repeated on each column/row of a matrix.  This includes addition, element-wise multiplication, etc.